# Autocomplete for visual studio code not working for C#/Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have just begun trying to learn C# with Unity. I'm following guides and tutorials. In these guides I see auto completions that my visual studio code is not showing me.

For example, in one video I see the following auto-completion:

[image]

On my own installation, I see the following:

[image]

Note that the auto-completion is not hinting `Destroy`. Other methods/functions such as `GetComponent` are also not auto-completed.

I believe that the correct folder is opened in VSC.

Visual studio code is set as my default editor in unity as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477235/visual-studio-code-intellisense-for-unity-not-working).
I have installed the `.Net Core Extension Pack`, which includes the C# extension pack for VSC. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you are missing some namespaces

Comment: I believe I'm using the same name spaces as in the example video. Would you know which name space I'm missing?

Comment: I would reinstall Unity and let it install VS automatically. It should work then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling code completion (For recent versions of Unity)
If you are installing VS Code for the first time, you might be missing targeting packs required for Unity's code-completion (IntelliSense) in VS Code.
Targeting pack download links:
• Windows: .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack
Download Link: https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=48136

• macOS: Download .NET SDK
Download link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Steps:

1. Stop VS Code or Unity running.
2. Download and install the targeting pack for your targeted framework version / preferred version from one of the above links.
3. Start Unity.
4. Create and/or open an existing script in VS Code, through Unity, and you should now see code completions.

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Comment: i have intellisense but i dont get the same auto completes as them and i turned off auto completes from unimported namespaces because it kept changing transform to cryptoapitransform but i dont know how to get the other auto completes