# Camera Methods not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity/C# dont find the method "Camera.ScreentoWorldSpace" or also "Camera.main".
i dont know why, i dont know if i just forget something, so please help.
I want to create a Raycast using the Mouse Position but when i wanted to use my main Camera to change the mouse Pos from screen Space to World Space it do not recognizes these Methods nor autocomplete it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Inspect_Button : MonoBehaviour
{
public string inspectName;
public Camera cam;

private GameObject markedLand;
private Vector3 mousePos;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
}


void OnEnable()
{
    markedLand = GameObject.Find(inspectName);

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        print(mousePos);
        cam.ScreentoWorldSpace(mousePos);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have another script/class that is also called „Camera“ in your project?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely an issue of Unity not generating your IDE's project file properly, leading to your IDE not detecting the Unity's API for auto-correct and such.

*On your Unity Editor,* **Edit -> Preferences...**

[image: Step_1]

**External Tools ->** *Ensure that the selected Editor is correct* -> **Regenerate Project Files** -> *Restart your IDE*

[image: Step_2]

---

Assuming you are using Visual-Studio and it still doesn't work, confirm there is Unity C# installed onto your Visual Studio, like so:
*(Use **Visual Studio Installer** to check)*

[image: Confirm]

[Solution for VS-Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314062/autocomplete-for-visual-studio-code-not-working-for-c-unity) instead.

---

Finally, `Camera.ScreenToWorldSpace` does *not* exists.
You are probably looking for [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

[`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) do exist though, and should work.