# Visual Studio Code no intellisense for C# Unity

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, mono

I'm on Linux and I set up Visual Studio code for game development with Unity and C# but when I open a script there is no Intellisense, the words are colored and I get suggestions for variables that are declared in the scope but I don't get the Classes of Unity.

This is the Visual Studio Code log:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 4/24/2022, 2:17:14 PM
    Target: /home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/3Dgame.sln

OmniSharp server started with Mono 6.8.0.
    Path: /home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 9311

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on linuxmint 20.3 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.11.0 - "/home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.11.0 - "/home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in '/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/3Dgame.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame' on host 9215.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.Rider.Editor.dll mtoken: 0x0a000007 due to: Could not find method '.ctor' due to a type load error: Could not set up parent class, due to: Could not set up parent class, due to:  assembly:/home/gabriel/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.31f1/Editor/Data/NetStandard/ref/2.0.0/netstandard.dll type:Object member:(null) assembly:/home/gabriel/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.31f1/Editor/Data/NetStandard/ref/2.0.0/netstandard.dll type:Attribute member:(null) assembly:/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll type:TestRunCallbackAttribute member:(null) assembly:/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll type:TestRunCallbackAttribute member:(null)
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task failed unexpectedly.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not find method '.ctor' due to a type load error: Could not set up parent class, due to: Could not set up parent class, due to:  assembly:/home/gabriel/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.31f1/Editor/Data/NetStandard/ref/2.0.0/netstandard.dll type:Object member:(null) assembly:/home/gabriel/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.31f1/Editor/Data/NetStandard/ref/2.0.0/netstandard.dll type:Attribute member:(null) assembly:/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll type:TestRunCallbackAttribute member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesDataInternal(System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider)
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesDataBase (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inheritedOnly) [0x00016] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesData (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00017] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.Assembly target) [0x00000] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributesData () [0x00000] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation.GetFrameworkName () [0x00025] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation.get_FrameworkNameAttribute () [0x00028] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyDependency.AssemblyMetadata..ctor (System.String path) [0x00019] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation+<>c.<GetAssemblyMetadata>b__21_0 (System.String p) [0x00000] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x0003d] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation.GetAssemblyMetadata (System.String path, System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] assemblyMetadataCache, Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension[]& dependencies, System.String[]& scatterFiles, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName& frameworkName) [0x00006] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_string_ConcurrentDictionary`2<string, AssemblyMetadata>_AssemblyNameExtension[]&_string[]&_FrameworkName&(string,System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2<string, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyDependency.AssemblyMetadata>,Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension[]&,string[]&,System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName&)
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SystemState.GetAssemblyMetadata (System.String path, System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] assemblyMetadataCache, Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension[]& dependencies, System.String[]& scatterFiles, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName& frameworkName) [0x00010] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.GetUnifiedAssemblyMetadata (Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Reference reference, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Build.Tasks.UnifiedAssemblyName]& unifiedDependencies, System.String[]& scatterFiles) [0x00023] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.FindDependenciesAndScatterFiles (Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Reference reference, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] newEntries) [0x0003a] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.FindAssociatedFiles () [0x000ea] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure () [0x0000a] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] remappedAssembliesValue, Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyFiles, Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyNames, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] exceptions) [0x00038] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute (Microsoft.Build.Shared.FileExists fileExists, Microsoft.Build.Shared.DirectoryExists directoryExists, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetDirectories getDirectories, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyName getAssemblyName, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyMetadata getAssemblyMetadata, Microsoft.Build.Shared.GetRegistrySubKeyNames getRegistrySubKeyNames, Microsoft.Build.Shared.GetRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue getRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetLastWriteTime getLastWriteTime, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyRuntimeVersion getRuntimeVersion, Microsoft.Build.Shared.OpenBaseKey openBaseKey, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyPathInGac getAssemblyPathInGac, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.IsWinMDFile isWinMDFile, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReadMachineTypeFromPEHeader readMachineTypeFromPEHeader) [0x00516] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute () [0x00000] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00029] in <3d628fd3ab3741f191fd8b2e89cd01c9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002fc] in <3d628fd3ab3741f191fd8b2e89cd01c9>:0 
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/home/gabriel/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12/.omnisharp/1.37.10/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2202,5): Error: The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task failed unexpectedly.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not find method '.ctor' due to a type load error: Could not set up parent class, due to: Could not set up parent class, due to:  assembly:/home/gabriel/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.31f1/Editor/Data/NetStandard/ref/2.0.0/netstandard.dll type:Object member:(null) assembly:/home/gabriel/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.31f1/Editor/Data/NetStandard/ref/2.0.0/netstandard.dll type:Attribute member:(null) assembly:/home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Library/ScriptAssemblies/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll type:TestRunCallbackAttribute member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesDataInternal(System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider)
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesDataBase (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inheritedOnly) [0x00016] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesData (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00017] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.Assembly target) [0x00000] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributesData () [0x00000] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation.GetFrameworkName () [0x00025] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation.get_FrameworkNameAttribute () [0x00028] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyDependency.AssemblyMetadata..ctor (System.String path) [0x00019] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation+<>c.<GetAssemblyMetadata>b__21_0 (System.String p) [0x00000] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x0003d] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyInformation.GetAssemblyMetadata (System.String path, System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] assemblyMetadataCache, Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension[]& dependencies, System.String[]& scatterFiles, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName& frameworkName) [0x00006] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_string_ConcurrentDictionary`2<string, AssemblyMetadata>_AssemblyNameExtension[]&_string[]&_FrameworkName&(string,System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2<string, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyDependency.AssemblyMetadata>,Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension[]&,string[]&,System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName&)
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SystemState.GetAssemblyMetadata (System.String path, System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] assemblyMetadataCache, Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension[]& dependencies, System.String[]& scatterFiles, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName& frameworkName) [0x00010] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.GetUnifiedAssemblyMetadata (Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Reference reference, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Build.Tasks.UnifiedAssemblyName]& unifiedDependencies, System.String[]& scatterFiles) [0x00023] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.FindDependenciesAndScatterFiles (Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Reference reference, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] newEntries) [0x0003a] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.FindAssociatedFiles () [0x000ea] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure () [0x0000a] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] remappedAssembliesValue, Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyFiles, Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyNames, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] exceptions) [0x00038] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute (Microsoft.Build.Shared.FileExists fileExists, Microsoft.Build.Shared.DirectoryExists directoryExists, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetDirectories getDirectories, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyName getAssemblyName, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyMetadata getAssemblyMetadata, Microsoft.Build.Shared.GetRegistrySubKeyNames getRegistrySubKeyNames, Microsoft.Build.Shared.GetRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue getRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetLastWriteTime getLastWriteTime, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyRuntimeVersion getRuntimeVersion, Microsoft.Build.Shared.OpenBaseKey openBaseKey, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GetAssemblyPathInGac getAssemblyPathInGac, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.IsWinMDFile isWinMDFile, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReadMachineTypeFromPEHeader readMachineTypeFromPEHeader) [0x00516] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute () [0x00000] in <816110c02eb3417e8d54b6b156d9f556>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00029] in <3d628fd3ab3741f191fd8b2e89cd01c9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002fc] in <3d628fd3ab3741f191fd8b2e89cd01c9>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
        Miscellaneous file: /home/gabriel/UnityProjects/3Dgame/Assets/Scripts/Test.cs added to workspace
Received response for /v2/getcodeactions but could not find request.
Received response for /v2/getcodeactions but could not find request.
```

I have Dot Net sdk version `6.0.202`

Dot Net runtime version : `6.0.4`

I have mono installed: `Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105`

And I'm using Unity `2020.3.31f1`

I'm on Linux Mint

Comment: Have you tried this solution here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63315583/7421086; Google up '.NET SDK for Linux', I saw a few official documentation for downloads.