# Visual Studio Code autocomplete with unity is not working on Mac

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to learn unity and some C#, however as you can read the autocomplete is not working with Visual Studio Code. I have tried the steps listed here: [Autocomplete for visual studio code not working for C#/Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314062/autocomplete-for-visual-studio-code-not-working-for-c-unity)

However, I am still met with the same error. Here is a link to the output: < [https://pastebin.pl/view/1b6f34b5>](https://pastebin.pl/view/1b6f34b5%3E)

Line 43 says my mono may not be up to date, but I have installed both packages from this link, which should be the right ones? https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

I'm not the most tech savy with code, so any help is appreciated. It seems others have had this issue but I can't seem to fix it.